# Использование TelegramBot в проекте Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, telegram-bot

Следую указаниям из инструкции https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Getting-Started.
Когда запускаю проект, появляется ошибка: `More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'.`

Выяснил, что эта ошибка возникает сразу, когда я указываю в зависимостях

```
implementation 'org.telegram:telegrambots:5.5.0'
```

даже в чистом проекте.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял из просмотренных мною материалов, эта ошибка возникает именно в Gradle на этапе компиляции из-за того, что Gradle в зависимостях проекта находит несколько одинаковых файлов (в данном случае `META-INF/DEPENDENCIES`) и не "знает", какой выбрать при упаковке APK. В файле `build.gradle` в разделе `android` я добавил

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/**"
    }
```

Теперь Gradle будет брать первый попавшийся файл из вызвавших коллизию файлов (так поступает Maven, на сколько я знаю).